# How do you generate SEO pages that match a large number of generic search phrases and locations?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I see that some sites in the Google search results have a matching page for almost any combination of specific keywords and locations. They also actually contain the search query within the page:

> We provide you services for << my search query >>

How is that possible? Do they have pre-generated pages for a list of keywords and locations? Or is there some way to dynamically compute the pages? In that case. How would the dynamic pages be in the Google results?

Answer (score 1):

this is a kind of SEO from middle age. Google punishs such sites with pretty low rankings. Specially Panda updates are targeting such sites. For the more keywords ranks a single one url, the better Google means about it and the higher it ranks. Got the idea? Not 1 keyword = 1 url, but 1 url = as more keywords as possible.

The technical part of doing such SEO spam like you described is pretty simple: something like a cron job pre-renders pages with placeholers, which are filled in from a keyword list/database.

Answer (score 0):

These pages are "pre-generated". The "dynamic computing" of pages would not be possible, as Google has to know and "rate" the page before giving it a (hopefully good) place within the serps.